# call XML data and display in table

Tags: php, html, xml, api

I am totally new to programming, but im trying to do , what i think is a simple task.

There is site, it has an api, the api has a module that im to call. In their api guide it says to use "get" and the url is

```
api.php?apikey="apikey"=sales&start=0&count=100"
```

.....,when I take the complete url , with my key correctly placed, and I put It in the url bar I get

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
>         IDBuyerText+Text----BEGIN+PGP+MESSAGE-----%0AVersion%3A+GnuPG+v1%0A%0AhQIMA16P%2F289ol6lARAAi6DPESNYX%2BNQnTmRHswbXfocwm8SAm49kg%2BHO9vtUBI5%0AVog4XfKVA6h7CHSEvixuL%2BwJSXSjSSM3nLWwo3sGVOf2oU%2FEiOmQNavQrYPE98a2%0A3hn%2Fzalf0S6kpYkqUr69hxbNY8ZkZmiyo0hRcKIw4WVoVcA8qROoORU8aTIggPnO%0ANu7YMSbJ1cWjoouxeJ2FoIaVhBl5qlKGZ2DUooLbNZrGf37H5aAnsh%2F23Lz0w%2FV7%0AeLq%2BVhqW72AnI9AQbnWeDp5ipRTFLWXoXvuUdPUgEVDPhUw5cvBE%2BX%2BEVssTh4p1%0AZgh6R4oNpxgo%2BsIqUgIEwy%2FidsBcjjayvcscxkk6t8rikBAVCRLLcyalRQ304uFt%0Ag355GptyXw4BWEVsZynYqo%2F6FNecWg8JKLjUvpqu%2BcVxgAWFBtvluJOQHFloYxlH%0Af9I8vuSJS1Z3Pc7ZG%2FAIBiCVh%2FeOx3IuO8JEuM0HIJdhp2TiRqD9A4b487kexELQ%0Ag%2BTyUPXzHBvHWQ5cL02PUFyhO4ZKKx3cqzTneRSdqQSLPhjR9QSJcur%2Fjh5h2Ml3%0Alb%2Fuyl9uM2RdZGJtSyoGVtGjICqmNasYfjdopY3xsttKZJz%2BeEI8NnqJyOp%2BfRtv%0AEXgnKNmMgqJpm%2Ff%2BO4pZZiW7%2BUlbR65YsfAAGdsrzpLVlnJjEczPl0WeW%2F1eIT3S%0AbQE7esXriSG3tc50l2ci1x2JX5gbHCsKaxLLSsCNpTmbHAcFGxH9ot%2F23hTf7%2F%2F4%0AfxDenrd1EK8iN6mv6ux6GnbHcP9ipMYKHZhxkfN6v1u%2BWJcjl9eEaRxKC3RaALT7%0Al8zhWPQbTngLh8P52Kc%3D%0A%3DbGSh%0A-----END+PGP+MESSAGE-----%0A

now this is what I'm totally lost on , and I imagine I'm doing wrong, there are no spaces between words, and their are characters like %0A, which I think are "CR" and line something, well there is no way I can decrypt the pgp with those characters, so how do I call them without those charcters, and how do I call the data into a table, displayed cleanly like

SALE ID      BUyer     TITLE     BUyer NOtes

thanks for any help

Comment: Seems that the data has encoding base64. So you decode the data and parse as xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this text in the response:

```
----BEGIN+PGP+MESSAGE-----

-----END+PGP+MESSAGE-----
```

That means that a message has been cryptographically signed.

Since the response you are getting is encrypted, you have to go over the guide again and check what mechanism you must follow to decrypt the message correctly.